# "Eclipse Template Issue: Unable to Trigger Templates with Shortcut (sysout), built in templates and self made templates code"

Tags: java, eclipse

Template in Eclipse is not working for me. I'm using a Macbook Air and I have installed the latest version of Eclipse. However, whenever I used my own template code or the built in code made by Eclipse it always shows no template proposals.

I recently want to add a couple more shortcut to my Ecplise. I toggled on the content assist and at first sysout with control space on mac could work. After adding some more code I made my self and press control space after, it says no template proposals. I also toggled on Java Template proposals, enabled auto insert for my code. After all of this, I pressed sysout it shows a method sub which then creates a method private void sysout(){. I checked the error logs and saw one error which command w has two commands. I changed that and still after it shows again no template proposals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are provided only where they make sense. For example, `sysout` makes sense in the body of a method or in a static code block. According to *"I pressed sysout it shows a method sub which then creates a method private void sysout(){"* you are at a location where `System.out.println();` would be invalid:

```
class Sample {
    
    // `sysout` template not(!) provided here
    
    {
        // `sysout` template provided here
    }
    
    void sample() {
        // `sysout` template provided here
    }

}
```

Comment: Ohhhh, Thank you very much, I thought the template is not working sometimes. In fact it only work in some occasions.